# Recover output of 2 python scripts with subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to launch two python scripts simultaneously from another script. It works with subprocess.Popen. But I also would like to recover the output of these two scripts launched simultaneously.

When I use subprocess.check_output, I manage to recover the outputs but the scripts are not launched at the same time.

I have made a simple example to illustrate the problem. The programm 2scripts.py calls the scripts aa.py and bb.py.

aa.py :

```
import time

delay = 0
t0 = time.time()
print "temps " + str(t0)
print("aa")
while delay < 5 :
    delay = time.time() - t0
```

bb.py :

```
import time

delay = 0
t0 = time.time()
print "temps " + str(t0)
print("bb")
while delay < 5 :
    delay = time.time() - t0
```

This is 2scripts.py and the output with subprocess.Popen :

2scripts.py :

```
import subprocess

x = subprocess.Popen((["python", "aa.py"]))
y = subprocess.Popen((["python", "bb.py"]))
```

> temps 1460040113.05
>   aa
>   temps 1460040113.05
>   bb

And 2scripts.py and the output with subprocess.check_output()

```
import subprocess

x = subprocess.check_output((["python", "aa.py"]))
y = subprocess.check_output((["python", "bb.py"]))
print(x)
print(y)
```

> temps 1460040186.3 
>   aa
>   temps 1460040191.31 
>   bb

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing.pool` to run both at the same time and only print the outputs when both have returned results. This way, they both start at the same time and you manage to get their outputs.

### Code:

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing.pool
import time

pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(2)
x,y = pool.map(lambda x: x(), [
        lambda: subprocess.check_output((["python", "aa.py"])),
        lambda: subprocess.check_output((["python", "bb.py"]))
    ])

print(x)
print(y)
```

### Output:

```
temps 1460050982.44
aa

temps 1460050982.44
bb
```

Comment: @Utopia - I made a small copy-paste error. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

An enhanced example of @Ru Hasha with number of thread as first command line parameter and only one script to illustrate the different command called.

**xscripts.py**

```
import sys, subprocess, multiprocessing.pool

nb_threads = int(sys.argv[1])
pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(nb_threads)

processes = []
for i in range(nb_threads):
    processes.append(lambda i=i: subprocess.check_output((["python", "mic.py", "mic" + str(i)])))

outputs = pool.map(lambda x: x(), processes)

for o in outputs:
    print o
```

**mic.py**

```
import sys, time

sys.stdout.write(sys.argv[1] + " start time\t" + str(time.time()) + '\n')
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write(sys.argv[1] + " end time\t" + str(time.time()))
```

**Output**

```
$ python xscripts.py 4
mic0 start time 1460071350.1
mic0 end time   1460071352.1
mic1 start time 1460071350.1
mic1 end time   1460071352.1
mic2 start time 1460071350.1
mic2 end time   1460071352.1
mic3 start time 1460071350.1
mic3 end time   1460071352.1
```